# Precompiling JSP and <jsp-file> tag

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have /WEB-INF/jsp/info/1.jsp which maps to URI /info/1:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>/info/1</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/info/1.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>/info/1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/info/1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After precompiling JSPs with jspc ant task from apache tomcat, the following lines added to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.info._1_jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.info._1_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.info._1_jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/info/1.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then when I navigate to /info/1, tomcat compiles JSP again. How do I correct this situation?

Comment: is there a reason to do that? an application server (tomcat) does that for you

Comment: It slows website after webapp updating because tomcat recompiles every jsp on first request and it takes sometimes few seconds for each jsp. With precompiling I can do it before deploying so thre's no performance impact.

Comment: what tomcat are u using? are you aware of the native tomcat? this should speed up things a bit for you http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi

Comment: @vbezhenar have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to correct the situation, since it is correctly set up. Every jsp-page gets compiled to a servlet class. What your precompiling is doing is basically what an application server does at runtime the first time a jsp-page is loaded.

Comment: OP wants to know why Tomcat is compiling JSPs that were pre-compiled.